# Java/Mockito - A unit test for the thread to sleep exponentially before retry

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to create a unit test class to test the class I created. This class tries to send a message and if it fails to send, it will wait exponentially (1s, 2s, 4s, 8s etc) before it retries to send the message. I want to test if this exponential wait behaviour works correctly. But I am new to unit testing and not really sure how to go about testing it using JUnit and Mockito. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
@Slf4j
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
public class RetriableProcessorExponentialDecorator implements   
        AbsMessageProcessorDecorator {
    private final AbsMessageProcessor messageProcessor;
    @Autowired
    private AbsMessageActiveMQConfiguration configuration;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(AbsMessage message) throws Exception {
        int executionCounter = 0;
        long delay = 1000;
        final int maxRetries = this.configuration.getExceptionRetry() + 1;
        do {
            executionCounter++;
            try {
                this.messageProcessor.onMessage(message);
            } catch (RetriableException e) {
                log.info("Failed to process message. Retry #{}", executionCounter);
                delay = (long) (delay * (Math.pow(this.configuration.getMultiplier(), executionCounter)));
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // We don't retry on this, only RetriableException.
                throw e;
            }
        } while (executionCounter < maxRetries && delay < Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

P.S Based on @Andy Turner's suggestion, I added a line `private final DefaultSleeper defaultSleeper;` in my **RetriableProcessorExponentialDecorator** class, and then replace `Thread.sleep(delay)` with `defaultSleeper.sleep(delay)`.

Then in my unit test class, I mocked **DefaultSleeper** by doing `@Mock
private DefaultSleeper sleeper;` and passed the mock object through the constructor of **RetriableProcessorExponentialDecorator** like the following:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.decorator = new   
    RetriableProcessorExponentialDecorator(sleeper, processor,   
    configuration);
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I would not test waiting, I would test it method that calculates wait time based on tries count returns correct results

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface something like this:

```
interface Sleeper {
  void sleep(long delay) throws InterruptedException;
}
```

Then you can create an implementation of this:

```
class DefaultSleeper implements Sleeper {
  @Override public void sleep(long delay) throws InterruptedException { 
    Thread.sleep(delay);
  }
}
```

and mock it: `Sleeper sleeper = mock(Sleeper.class);`.

Now you can inject an instance of this into your `RetriableProcessorExponentialDecorator`, and test for interactions with the mock in your test.

Comment: Is it possible that you can show the injecting of instance and testing interaction part as well? I am not really sure if I fully understand these parts

Comment: Pass by contructor for example.

Comment: By injecting an instance of _this_ do you mean, I should replace the current Thread.sleep(delay); (which is in the catch phrase in my current code) with the instanceName.sleep(delay)?